# How to integrate a different (JavaScript) editor in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor

I'been using WordPress since 2005 and although I'm pretty much conquered in all respects, I still wonder **how some possibilities** are not there for the user.

One of them: **changing the default TinyMCE editor** and replacing it with other modern alternatives. The popularity growth of the Markup language is clear, and the new [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) CMS makes a point in this respect. Why does WordPress not support this fully either natively or with an official plugin?

I will go even further: **I'd like to use whatever editor I want**. In my case, the [Medium](http://www.medium.com) editor is absolutelly stunning, and I'd be delighted to be able to combine that editor to the other WordPress features.

There are [several alternatives](http://www.codersgrid.com/2013/09/04/medium-editor-ui-zenpen-grande-js-and-pen-editor/) programmed in JavaScript that allow to use an editor similar to Medium's, and **I wonder if it would be possible to integrate that into WordPress**. I guess it's not just a matter of the JavaScript, but the relation of the editor with the database.

How can I integrate a different editor (for example, one of the JavaScript ones that copy the Medium one, like [Pen Editor](https://github.com/sofish/pen) in WordPress??

Comment: sorry, but this is more of a rant then a question. can you please edit it so it will be clear what exactly are you asking? If the question is if it is possible to integrate different editors then the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks, edited. This is a question, although I wanted to be a little more creative than the usual "How to...?". If that is possible, can you point me how?? Thx!

Comment: in the end all editors work the same, you have a textarea in which the edited content is stored before posting and JS that replace it for the actual editing. It has been a long while since I took a look at it but there should be plugins that integrate other editors like cfkeditor.

Comment: you may want to take a look at how the [ckeditor for WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/) does it.